# Adding CSS animation buttons to Excel with VBA

Tags: css, excel, vba, user-interface, button

I came across [this webpage with some beautiful animated buttons](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReeEyx) . I have a few buttons in an Excel Workbook that activate some VBA projects, and I was wondering if I could add the buttons I found into that Excel Workbook. I have no knowledge of integrating different languages into VBA, except for some SQL.

**Any way this could be possible?**

P.S. Button 1 (diagonal swipe) is all I need, CCS code below

```
.btn-1 {
  $btn-color: random-color($max:200);
  $btn-color-dark: shade($btn-color, 40%);
  color: tint($btn-color);

  &:before {
    content: '';
    @include absolute(0,-50px,0,0);
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: $btn-height solid $btn-color-dark;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  &:hover {
    color: tint($btn-color, 75%);

    &:before {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/802479/how-can-i-trigger-an-excel-macro-by-hovering-a-mouse-over-a-cell

Comment: @QHarr I'm not looking for a mouseover event, I'm looking to insert the button's CSS code into my VBA macro.

Comment: You would have to translate the effect as CSS is not for VBA objects. One way, is through the use of transparent labels with mouseover events that trigger code.

Comment: In that case, I don't think it's possible to do what I want at all. Have you taken a look at the webpage? The buttons use complex animations I don't think are replicable with VBA code. 
Is there any way I can insert a non-VBA object? I'm really pushing the limits of my coding knowledge here. If I can't add CSS code to a regular VBA button, perhaps I can create a button-like object myself?

Comment: I haven't logged in to view what is here: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1047801-how-to-combine-css-html-and-vba-to-produce-customized-buttons-on-an-outlook-email.html

Comment: That thread is about adding CSS to an e-mail body, I'll have to look whether that's applicable to my worksheet once I'm back in the office

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't include mouseover events, so it's not likely without maybe some API hacks. There are some mouseMove events that would require defining hotspots for each button, but in order for it to work, your CPU would basically be processing a sub every time you moved your mouse. I don't think it would be great for performance, but maybe someone here could correct me.

Take a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mousemove-event) from Microsoft for more information on the mouseMove event.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ox.
I'm aware of this event, I'm instead looking for information on how to add the button code (which is in CSS) to a VBA macro.

Comment: @TimStack Right, I see that--my comment was that your CSS includes "hover," which would translate into a mouseover event. So you wouldn't be able to take advantage of the hover feature here.